# Fix Anchoring when changing parent

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, anchor, parent

I have a RichTextBox, a Button and a List Box with Anchor set to Top, Bottom, Right.
 Whenever I change the form size and then change their parent (from one tab of a TabControl to another) their position gets messed up.

http://imgur.com/WiQhRJU,FyFIQTL,7K7HMTt,Nqrm20y

First image: Before re-size ✓
Second image: After re-size ✓
Third image: After re-size on different tab ✖
Fourth image: Switched back to original tab ✖

This is the code i use to change the parent:

```
private void tabTabs_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (tabTabs.SelectedTab == tabChat || tabTabs.SelectedTab == tabCmd)
    {
        lstUsers.Parent = tabTabs.TabPages[tabTabs.SelectedIndex];
        rtbSend.Parent = tabTabs.TabPages[tabTabs.SelectedIndex];
        btnSend.Parent = tabTabs.TabPages[tabTabs.SelectedIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Often a Refresh will enforce the new layout..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm a year late, but I just had this same problem with tabs and anchoring. How I fixed it was by adding a panel that contains all of the elements and setting Dock to Fill. Then by only changing that container panel's parent, it worked flawlessly. In reality this is a bug that should be reported to MS, but for now this workaround works wonderfully.

Edit: You can also reduce/remove flicking when changing tabs by double buffering all of the controls including the tab group, tab pages, container panels, and all of the elements inside the container panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly unusual way to do a user interface. Not that it's necessarily wrong, but I think you're encountering one of the many potential difficulties that this design creates.

The main problem is that you are reusing user interface elements for different functions. A chat box becomes a command box on a different tab, a "send" button will send chat messages on one tab and commands on another tab, etc. Every time you switch tabs, you'll have to be extremely careful to do a lot of house cleaning and do it correctly. It just sounds overly complex.

Most user interfaces would be designed using multiple text boxes, buttons, etc., one for each tab. Each text box or button would serve one single purpose. If you need several different elements to look and behave similarly, you can use styles, templates, or create your own UserControls to help facilitate that.

The exception to that rule would be your viewer list. It looks as if that always stays the same regardless of what tab you're on. If it were me, I'd only have one instance of the viewer list, but I wouldn't put that in the tab control. I'd just place it next to the tab control so you can always see it.

Comment: The Command Box and Chat box are separate, but I see what you mean about the button and the text box